# SQL Server: Correct Estimation of Rows from String Split Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, split

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have a multi-statement table value function for splitting a string into a table via a delimiter.

I am not splitting long strings but I use this function in stored procedures like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.example
  @parameters
AS
Begin
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN Table B on B.ID = A.FID
WHERE B.ID IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.fn_Split(@parameters, ',')
END
```

The real sproc has multi-joins and many parameters. When I looked at the execution plan, the operator Table Scan (fn_split) Cost 0% always returned an inaccurate estimation of rows. For 11 parameters, it will estimated 100 rows.

I heard multi-statement table value function are slow, but using [inline](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html), 
[XML](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), or Jeff Moden's splitter are slower that my orginial one when used in the WHERE clause. They have horrible execution plans and worst estimations of rows

Is there a way to get correct estimation of rows when splitting a string into a table?

My function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_Split(    
  @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
 DECLARE @Iterator INT
 SET @Iterator = 1
 DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
 SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)
 WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
    SELECT 
        Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))
    SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
            @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
            LEN(@RowData))
    SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
END
INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))
RETURN
END
```

Comment: It's not possible for the optimizer to know the amount of rows because it can't analyze the behaviour of your function + value of the parameters when making the plan. I would assume your best bet is to use a temporary table, since it has statistics

Comment: 3 words -- table valued parameter

Comment: I would love to see your test setup and test data that proves that your WHILE loop version is as fast as you say and can beat things like DelimitedSplit8K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a temporary table?

```
Begin
    create table #split (data varchar(255) primary key);

    insert into #split(data)
        select data
        from dbo.fn_Split(@parameters, ',');

    SELECT *
    FROM TableA LEFT JOIN
         Table B
         on B.ID = A.FID
    WHERE B.ID IN (SELECT Data FROM #split);

END;
```

Comment: @Hogan it could provide the same basic functionality, but it might may or may not be as efficient. Table variables, temp tables, and CTEs can all be used to store data temporarily inside the query. However, the way that SQL Server determines row estimates can vary depending on which one is used, along with how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies necroing a 6 month old post but I thought the OP might still be listening and it may help others in the future.

I've documented most of what I wanted to say in the comments in the code.  Seems like it makes more sense "insitu" like that.

Before we get started though, any claims of performance on my or anyone's part should be looked at carefully, especially without coded proof.  With that in mind, let's first build a couple of million row test tables so that we can do some performance checking and proofing.

Here's the code for the test tables...

```
--=================================================================================================
--      Create and populate the two test tables.
--      Nothing in this section is a part of the solution. We're just setting up a test.
--=================================================================================================
--===== Drop the two test tables to make reruns in SSMS easier
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableA','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableB','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
GO
--===== Create the two test tables. I'm assuming some form of index on the 2 columns in question.
 CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (FID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
 CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB (ID  BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

--===== Populate TableA with a sequence from 1 to a million.
 INSERT INTO dbo.TableA WITH(TABLOCK)
        (FID)
 SELECT TOP 1000000
        FID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
   FROM      sys.all_columns ac1 --CROSS JOIN acts like a looped rowsource (Pseudo-Cursor)
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2 --and uses nothing from these tables except the presence of rows.
;
--===== Populate TableB with a sequence from 1 to 10,000 with a couple of pieces missing that
     -- will appear in @Parameters for testing.
 INSERT INTO dbo.TableB WITH(TABLOCK)
        (ID)
 SELECT ID = FID
   FROM dbo.TableA
  WHERE FID NOT IN (7363,805,34) --We'll include these in @Parameters for testing.
;
GO
```

Now, let's explore why the original code might be so slow when the DelimitedSplit8K function is used.  Turn on the Actual Execution Plan, run the following, and check out the comments in the code to understand why it takes nearly 3 seconds to run even on such simple and well indexed tables.

```
--=================================================================================================
--      Let's see why the original query using the dbo.DelimitedSplit8K function might be so slow.
--      After making minor corrections to the original code, here's what we end up with.  Run it
--      with the actual execution plan and discover two things.
--      1. The query is not SARGable and causes clustered index scans on both tables.
--      2. Because of the way the query was designed, the TABLE SPOOL is actually the result of a
--         CROSS JOIN between the 8 elements in the parameters and result of the JOIN between 
--         TableA and TableB. In other words, it has to generate nearly 8 million internal rows in
--         this case.  Imagine if you had 50 elements in your @Parameters.
--
--      Bottom line is that it's not the DelimitedSplit8K function that's slow. It's the way the
--      optimizer used an iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function) in this case and WHERE IN can
--      sometimes create a case of "HIDDEN RBAR".
--
--      P.S. The LEFT OUTER JOIN acts as if it where an inner join here because of the limit you've
--      placed on the RIGHT table with the function.
--=================================================================================================
--===== Start measuring stuff. NEVER do this with a SCALAR or mTVF (Multi-statment Table Valued
     -- function because it will make them seem hundreds of times slower. The proof is too long to
     -- show here so here's a reference for you. If you don't want to join to read the article
     -- (not sure you need to anymore), then you'll have to test that on your own.
     -- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/ "How to make Scalar UDFs Run Faster"
    SET STATISTICS IO,TIME ON
;
--===== Simulate the stored procedure having parameters passed to it.
DECLARE @Parameters VARCHAR(8000);  
 SELECT @Parameters = '8097,345,7363,805,34,8745,13,987654'
;
     -- Corrected code from the original post using DelimitedSplit8K instead of fnSplit.
 SELECT *
   FROM      TableA a
   LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.FID
  WHERE b.ID IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@parameters, ','))
;
--===== Stop measuring stuff.
    SET STATISTICS IO,TIME OFF
;
GO
```

You can see the accidental CROSS JOIN in the "worktable" in statistics output below. 2,000,054 reads is 16.38GB of data created internally. THAT takes a long time.

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(5 row(s) affected)
Table 'TableA'. Scan count 5, logical reads 2126, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'TableB'. Scan count 5, logical reads 2309, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 4, logical reads 2000054, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 11670 ms,  elapsed time = 3163 ms.
```

As you can see, iTVFs (Inline Table Valued Functions) can be a little persnickety.  Let's see what happens when we use it in a join.  And checkout the actual row counts in the Actual Execution plan compared to the original code above.

```
--=================================================================================================
--      If we use the iTVF (DelimitedSplit8K) in a JOIN instead of in a WHERE, there is no 
--      accidental CROSS JOIN because the results of the function are materialized just once.
--      The results are returned more than 3100 times faster.
--=================================================================================================
--===== Start measuring stuff.
    SET STATISTICS IO,TIME ON
;
--===== Simulate the stored procedure having parameters passed to it.
DECLARE @Parameters VARCHAR(8000);  
 SELECT @Parameters = '8097,345,7363,805,34,8745,13,987654'
;
 SELECT a.*,b.* 
   FROM dbo.TableA a
   LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b
     ON a.FID = b.ID --I make my ON statements look like the outer join for ease of reading
   JOIN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@parameters, ',')) s
     ON b.ID = s.Item
;
--===== Stop measuring stuff.
    SET STATISTICS IO,TIME OFF
;
GO
```

Here are the run results for that code.  More than 3100 times faster and more than 42,000 times less I/O in the form of logical reads (even memory performance benefits with that 5 orders of magnitude improvement).

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(5 row(s) affected)
Table 'TableA'. Scan count 0, logical reads 19, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'TableB'. Scan count 0, logical reads 28, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

p.s.  The estimates for how many rows will be returned from each of the tables is still just "1" probably because the function builds its own Tally-like structure on-the-fly.  Not sure it matters in this case, though.